# unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'byte array' and 'int' (bitwise operator)

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, operators, byte

I'm trying to make some calculations with a `bytearray` for a hashing algorithm but keep getting an error about `^` operand types.  I already made some other methods that seem to work well, but with this method it keeps getting an error.  Below is the code:

```
def showstate(a):
    i = 0
    buf = bytearray()
    width = 17
    print (type(a))
    while i < 8 * width:
        buf.append(buf ^  (1 and a[i])<<(7-(i%8)))
        #buf ^= (1 and a[i])<<(7-(i%8))
        #print ("absc")
        if  (((i%8) == 7) and (i)):
            print("%02x"%buf, end = '')
            buf = 0
        i += 1
```

I already tried to look the type of data that `a` had -- it says `bytearray`  I don't see any problem with the calculation of `buf`. Why does it always error with:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'bytearray' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that sometimes you're treating `buf` as a container:

```
buf = bytearray()
```

And sometimes you're treating `buf` as a number:

```
print("%02x"%buf, end = '')
buf = 0
```

And sometimes you're doing both in the same line:

```
buf.append(buf ^  (1 and a[i])<<(7-(i%8)))
```

Are these two different variables that need their own names or do you mean to index into `buf` when you're treating it as a number?